# Checking existence of hash key without hasOwnProperty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given this example data:

```
let foo = [1,2,2,3,5,3]
let seen = {}
```

What is the difference between the following ways to check the existence of a key?  Can I run into some hiccups using the first way?

```
foo.filter(function(item) {
    return seen[item] ? false : (seen[item] = true);
});
```

vs.

```
foo.filter(function(item) {
    return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
});
```

Comment: Also note that while the code provided is very common (abusing objects as hashmaps, checklists with properties), it is generally not very clean. Apart from issues already mentioned (prototype properties, falsy values, ...), properties can also only be strings (or symbols, but lets disregard that here). E.g. for `foo = [{ valA: "a" }, { valB: "b" }]`, the two objects will be treated as duplicates, although they absolutely are not (both coerced to string give "[object Object]"). As TJ noted at the end: Set or Map are more suited, at least in production code. For hacky snippets, whatever works :P

Comment: thanks @ASDFGerte.  So if I wanted to remove the duplicates without manipulating the array, how would I do that then using a Map ?  Would I be forced create a new array based on the non-duplicate items come across in the array?

Comment: `let seen = new Map(); let result = foo.filter(e => { if (seen.has(e)) return false; else { seen.set(e); return true; } });`

Comment: Or the quick and dirty way, `let result = [...new Set(foo)];` (has some unnecessary overhead). Note that both of these use the same as `===` for equality, meaning e.g. `foo = [{ a: 0 }, { a: 0 }]` is duplicate free (the two (!) objects are not identical). `let o = { a: 0 }; let foo = [o, o];` on the other hand has duplicates in this regard, `o === o`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte in the interests of being concise, does this work as well?  `let seen = new Map();` 
`let result = foo.filter(e => { if (!seen.has(e)) { seen.set(e); return e; } });` .  leaving out the `false`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, as shown in the question, both are incorrect because you're not using the return value of `filter` (a new, filtered array). Use `forEach` or (on modern systems) `for-of` in that case. But perhaps you actually are using it and just didn't show that in your question.

Addressing your main question:

The first way will incorrectly assume something wasn't seen if it's *falsy*. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`. (All other values are *truthy*.) Your second way will handle those correctly.

Another difference between your two checks is that the first gets the property regardless of where it is in the prototype chain; the second only looks at the object itself (which is probably what you want). For your example object, this really only matters for properties provided by `Object.prototype` such as `valueOf`, but...

You might also look into [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Thanks TJ.  Can you clarify what you meant in your first point re: not using the return value of the new filtered array.

Comment: @user10108817 - The purpose of `filter` is to create a new array that only contains the items your callback returns a truthy value for, so `newArray = originalArray.filter(callback)`. If you're not using the return value, `filter`'s not the right tool for looping through the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:
there are no problems in this case for not using `Object.hasOwnProperty()` [[wiki]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

**When would it be a problem?**

```js
let seen = {}

console.log(seen["constructor"]) // function Object() { [native code] }
```

as you can see this will also hold other strings for inherited properties like `constructor` of an Object. Since you are only dealing with numbers there a no such properties on Object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what TJ said.

hasOwnProperty will not search the prototype of the object while the bracket or dot notation will. See this example

```js
Object.prototype.foo = 1;
var baz = {"bar": 1}

if (baz.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
    console.log('has foo');
    return true
}

if (baz.bar) {
    console.log('has bar'); // has bar
    return true;
}
```